# Exclude sheets from running the macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code

```
Sub x()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim cht As ChartObject

For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each cht In Sht.ChartObjects
        With cht.Chart
            .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
    Next cht


If Sht.Name <> "NAMEOFSHEET, NAMEOFSHEET2" Then

For Each cht In Sht.ChartObjects
        With cht.Chart
            .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
            .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1
        End With
    Next cht
Else
'do nothing
    
End If

Next Sht

End Sub
```

The problem being that when I run it, it still includes the sheets I named in `"If Sht.Name <> "NAMEOFSHEET, NAMEOFSHEET2" Then`

However, if I just put one sheet name it works fine.

I tried to separate them outside the qoutes as such

```
If Sht.Name <> "NAMEOFSHEET", "NAMEOFSHEET2" Then
```

And I also tried to create another line for every different sheet.

```
If Sht.Name <> "NAMEOFSHEET"  Then
If Sht.Name <> "NAMEOFSHEET2"  Then
```

None of them works.

Any idea if this is possible and how to?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement

Comment: `If Sht.Name <> "NAMEOFSHEET" And Sht.Name <> "NAMEOFSHEET2" Then`

Comment: Thank you!  I will try it.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
If sht.Name <> "NAMEOFSHEET" And sht.Name <> "NAMEOFSHEET2" Then
```

Comment: Glad i could help.

Comment: Should it be with OR? Btw in case you have too many sheets, I would use a dictionary + `.Exists`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Instr` and combine all sheet names that you don't want the code to be executed for.
Instr will return a number indicating the position of the string you are looking for. And will return -1 if the substring was not found.

```
If Instr("NAMEOFSHEET, NAMEOFSHEET2", Sht.Name) < 0 Then
    ... your code here ...
End If
```

But you will need to watch out for sheet names that overlap. For example:

```
NAMEOFSHEET    is found in "NAMEOFSHEET, NAMEOFSHEET2"
NAMEOFSHEET2   is found in "NAMEOFSHEET, NAMEOFSHEET2"
NAMEOFSHEET3   is not found
NAME           is found
SHEET4         is not found
SHEET          is found
EET, NAM       is found
```

So you will need to give each sheet a unique name and mind the overlapping strings.